# Erlang error codes, need more details

Tags: erlang

I am trying to use the file:open(....) function in erlang but it doesn't seem to work. I keep getting an {error, eio} exception.

Ive looked into it in the erlang documentation and all i have found is that it is the posix error for input/output... go figure.

The file name im outputting in is in the formation of "C:/directory/file.txt"
Im not sure if this has something to do with it.

Is there anyway i can make erlang give me a more specific explanation to what is wrong?

Thanks, 
Jack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not know of a way to find out more without peeking inside the Erlang/VM.

If you look in the windows erlang source code there are a bunch of different errors which could cause en eio error. You can find a list of them [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/erts/emulator/drivers/win32/win_efile.c#L155). In order to figure out which specific one it is, I would attach with windbg and step through the code as instrumenting and recompiling it on windows is a pain.

You might also be able to use something like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to find out which system calls are being made and what they return.